# Siri suggestions are buggy in iOS 16

Tags: ios, sirikit

I added siri suggestion to the app for a while,it works well.But some day,as shown in the picture,when I clicked on my siri suggestion, it opened another app.

If the system showed siri suggestion to my app, why did it open another app by mistake? Can someone tell me what the reason is?

Comment: There is no image in the question, so it looks unclear what is exactly problem that you're trying to fix